# GLM and estimation in R

Tags: statistics, regression

Consider your data are $(Y_1,X_1)$, ... $(Y_{1000},X_{1000})$ iid and the following holds:

$$Y|X\sim Beta(X\beta, 1).$$

I want to estimate $\beta$. What is the function in R that gives me this estimate and its confidence intervals? I understand that using ML to obtain this $\beta$ is theoretically easy, but coding it is quite ugly, and I am sure there must be a function for this.

Comment: Can you say $Y_i \in (0,1)$ and $X_i>0$? If so, the maximum likelihood estimator does not look too difficult

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $Y_i \in (0, 1)$ and $X_i > 0$, the likelihood is
$$L(\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n X_i\beta Y_i^{X_i \beta - 1}$$
so the log-likelihood is
$$\log L(\beta) = \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i \beta - 1) \log Y_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \log X_i + n \log \beta$$
Take the derivative with respect to $\beta$ and set it equal to zero. Solving the resulting equation for $\beta$ gives you a simple expression for the MLE.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know this, but I have problems with how to do this in R in practice. If beta is a vector, maximizing this function is multidimensional optimization problem, and I don't know how to implement it in R. But I am sure that there is a way how super easily implement it straightforwardly with one GLM function, but I don't know how

Comment: @AlbertParadek Is there a reason why you think the implementation in R is not simply computing the final expression $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \log Y_i$? There is no reason to implement an optimization problem when you have a simple expression for the MLE. As for cases where $\beta$ is a vector you should specify which problem you have in mind. If $X$ is a vector of the same shape and you have $X^\top \beta$, then the MLE for $\beta$ will similarly be the vector $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n (\log Y_i) X_i$. If you have a different problem in mind you should say so.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. For some reason I thought that its not this simple for multivariate X. But it works. Thanks

Comment: It should be $\frac{-n}{\sum X_i log(Y_i)}$ thouhg. You put $1/X_i\beta$ and it should be just $X_i\beta$. But this is maybe due to different interpretation of the coefficient in beta distribution

Comment: @AlbertParadek Yes sorry thanks for the corrections. I've corrected my post but I can't edit my previous comment.